# how to prevent the else block to get run if "if block" works in loops

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js

I have a code block like this
[image: it is javascript code which compares the outer loop with inner loop]

but I don't know how to prevent the "else block" from happening when "if block" works,
it is the picture of the console when this run
[image: the picture of the console showing the result]

Comment: What does this have to do with C# or C++?

Comment: Put the code in the question as _text_ and select _one_ language tag.

Comment: The `else` block does not run in the same cases where the `if` block runs.

I think what you're trying to do is search if an item is in a collection, but what happens is that you go through every item in the collection and compare it with `commodityModelInId`. You get the `if` block when the item matches, and the `else` block when it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to loop through each item in your iterate list and if it matches something in the stock list then do something. Your loop is looking at every item in the iterate list and every item of the stock list and comparing them. That means every item in the iterate list will get a console log for every item in the stock list.

Instead of looping through both list, loop through the first list and then search the second list for any matching item. If one is found, then do your action (console.log).

This is in C#, but it might help.

```
listToIterate.ForEach(elementToIterate =>
{
  var id = elementToIterate;
  if(listInStock.Any(elementInStock => elementInStock == id))
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Exists");
  }
  else
  {
     Console.WriteLine("Not Exists");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the condition of an if statement is true, the code will never proceed into the else statement. Keep in mind that you are running your code in a loop; the log messages that you are seeing are each from different iteration in a loop. This can be seen from the fact that the `id` of the object you are printing out is different every iteration.

Comment: so how to compare an outer loop with inner loop?

Comment: If you only wish to find the objects that match the `id`, you do not need an `else` block

Comment: that is not different, every alternative id is the same

Comment: in else block will run another logic, it is just a simple console.log but if the 'if bock' doesn't work then the else block will get run

Comment: Yes it will get run for each object where the condition is not met.